# Update with a Min in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, min

I want to update a Column in a Table, based on the minimum of another column of the same table.

eg.

```
JobPositonId | JobPositonName | JobDescriptionId | ContactId
1            | 1              | 1                | 1
2            | 1              | 1                | 0
3            | 1              | 1                | 0
```

I want to update ContactId to be 1, if it is 0 and where JobPositionId is the lowest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
update jobTable
   set contactid = 1
 where jobPostitionId in (select pos from (select min(jobPositionId) as pos from jobTable where contactId = 0) as subtable);
```

It's kind of a hack similar to what's described here (http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/).

Comment: Did it work for what you needed? (It's always tough to know when not having the database set up to test against locally.)